# @protocol with @class defintition

Tags: objective-c

I am reading through some code in AQGrid and came accross:

```
@protocol AQGridViewDataSource;
@class AQGridView, AQGridViewData, AQGridViewUpdateInfo;

@protocol AQGridViewDelegate <NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@optional
....
```

What is the @class for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a forward declaration.

The very next line in that file is

```
- (void) gridView: (AQGridView *) gridView willDisplayCell: (AQGridViewCell *) cell forItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;
```

The `@class AQGridView...` let's the compiler know that there is a class called `AQGridView` that will be available at some point (it will be `#import`'ed when you need to actually use the `AQGridView` that is passed as an argument).